# Pandas - Search and amend Df with Df1 based on non-matching timeseries

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling to find a way to iterate over Df, and for each row, apply a definition that iterates to search for the nearest match in Df1 (with the aim to add data from Df1 to Df). Read and tried a lot of methods found here, but not winning. Would appreciate some pointers, especially if I'm going the wrong route:

Df (example) - For each row, take the datetime (I have removed it as the index), and search through Df1 for the closest match in time, and then add (in this case Offshore_Umgeni_Deep at 09:03) to Df [new column]'.

```
       datetime                    cond06     temp03     pres07  
0      2015-02-26 09:03:38.833000  49.448935  22.162381  10.909805   
1             2015-02-26 09:03:39  50.098050  22.162781  10.885601   
2      2015-02-26 09:03:39.167000  50.060446  22.164354  10.807413   
3      2015-02-26 09:03:39.333000  50.239644  22.156575  10.788496   
4      2015-02-26 09:03:39.500000  50.179168  22.160942  10.803082
```

Df1:

```
      datetime             S         E         Location_Name
0     2015-02-26 09:01:00  29.81192  31.04692  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
1     2015-02-26 09:01:00  29.81176  31.04688  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
2     2015-02-26 09:01:00  29.81159  31.04682  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
3     2015-02-26 09:02:00  29.81140  31.04676  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
4     2015-02-26 09:02:00  29.81127  31.04673  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
5     2015-02-26 09:02:00  29.81116  31.04671  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
6     2015-02-26 09:02:00  29.81110  31.04670  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
7     2015-02-26 09:02:00  29.81109  31.04673  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
8     2015-02-26 09:02:00  29.81107  31.04674  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
9     2015-02-26 09:02:00  29.81105  31.04673  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
10    2015-02-26 09:02:00  29.81103  31.04673  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
11    2015-02-26 09:02:00  29.81103  31.04672  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
12    2015-02-26 09:02:00  29.81103  31.04669  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
13    2015-02-26 09:03:00  29.81102  31.04666  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
14    2015-02-26 09:03:00  29.81103  31.04664  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
15    2015-02-26 09:03:00  29.81104  31.04663  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
16    2015-02-26 09:03:00  29.81105  31.04661  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
17    2015-02-26 09:03:00  29.81106  31.04660  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
18    2015-02-26 09:03:00  29.81107  31.04657  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
19    2015-02-26 09:03:00  29.81109  31.04655  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
20    2015-02-26 09:03:00  29.81110  31.04653  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
21    2015-02-26 09:03:00  29.81111  31.04650  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
22    2015-02-26 09:04:00  29.81113  31.04649  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
23    2015-02-26 09:04:00  29.81114  31.04647  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
24    2015-02-26 09:04:00  29.81116  31.04646  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
25    2015-02-26 09:04:00  29.81117  31.04642  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
26    2015-02-26 09:04:00  29.81118  31.04640  Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
```

I could work with only HH:MM, but I may miss data, so I've been trying to use a least error method. After numerous attempts, I think it would be best to iterate over Df with a def that iterates through Df1:

```
def timesearch(df, df1):
    for datetime, row in df1.datetime.iteritems():
        if abs(df1['datetime'] - df['datetime']) < error:
            return (df['Location_Name'] = df1['Location_Name'])
        else:
            return (df["Location_Name"] = None))

for datetime, row in df.datetime.iteritems():
    def timesearch(df1.datetime,df2.datetime)
```

I know the above it not quite right as somehow while iterating it needs to know the row index to return from Df1 to Df. But hopefully I've exaplained concisely enough to get the idea accross.

Comment: what's your result output supposed to look like?

Comment: It seems like this sort of question comes up a lot and there isn't a really simple solution in pandas.  If you search SO on "nearest match merge join" you will find a few workarounds though.

Comment: If you know SQL, it might be easiest to merge that way, since the ```on``` in ```inner join``` will allow for more flexibility than the ```on``` in pandas ```merge```.

Comment: Thanks acushner and JohnE for the pointers. Will get onto them and see what I can find. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @acushner - In terms of what is should look like: (df would have Umgeni added from df1 as the time is nearest at 9:03)                       datetime                     cond06 temp03 pres07 Location_Name
0      2015-02-26 09:03:38.833000 49.448935 22.162381 10.909805 Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
1             2015-02-26 09:03:39 50.09805 22.162781 10.885601 Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
2      2015-02-26 09:03:39.167000 50.060446 22.164354 10.807413 Offshore_Umgeni_Deep
3      2015-02-26 09:03:39.333000 50.239644 22.156575 10.788496 Offshore_Umgeni_Deep